# The Stack Overflow site makes use of an SHA-1 certificate

Tags: feature-request

I was viewing Stack Overflow for questions. Then I saw one error notification in the Firefox debug tool. I further inspected and found this:

> This site makes use of an [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.

Why are they not using some better algorithm?

Comment: Making everything work under https is a work in progress. Having certificates with an up to date signature algorithm is the least of the worries I guess....

Comment: It seems that the certificate is from CDN provider Cloudflare.

Comment: @rene - I'd rather have no signature algorithm than an insecure one, as it gives a false sense of confidence. However, although SHA1 needs replacing I don't think it is an immediate threat to the security of the site.

Comment: I guess there's secure and there's insecure. And then there's the grey area in between.   My guess is that there's a limited risk to users of this site to people capturing your credentials and then posting questions under your name. Worse case scenario: you need to register a new account and start again with no reputation.  It's hardly a mugging at knifepoint, is it?

Comment: I agree with @Alex - provided no financial details are being handled personally I'm happy with even the most basic level of encryption. However, this is probably partly due to my naivety and complete lack of knowledge as to how one would penetrate even the most basic website security. If there was a subscription element or something more sensitive was involved (even if not financial details) then I would strongly back upgrading the security.

Comment: @Sam You've got your wish, then, as all you have to do is visit the site using the http protocol and you'll have no TLS. Even if you're logged in. I, for one, think your preference is ridiculous, though.

Comment: @Alex You're forgetting about the millions of users who reuse their credentials on every single site they own accounts on. So while the credentials for SO might be worthless on SO, they might be worth a complete mail account, or a nice online banking account somewhere else.

Comment: @Alex I don't think it's just the matter of limited risk of people posting questions under your name, but rather than it would still be quite difficult to craft a fake certificate that had the same SHA-1 signature as SO's legitimate certificate. SHA-1 isn't the best thing out there and it is time to start transitioning away from it to something stronger, but it's not like anything that uses SHA-1 is now fundamentally broken and everyone must switch by tomorrow or the whole Internet will be insecure.

Answer (score 39):

So it looks like SO doesn't run its own certificate but uses [Cloudflare's Universal SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl). What surprises me is that they have any SHA1 certificates

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=stackoverflow.com&s=104.16.104.85&hideResults=on

I ran the same test against a website I have behind Cloudflare and it came back with a SHA256 certificate. So this server just appears to have not yet been updated yet. From the [Cloudflare blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-and-sha-1-certificates/)

> Sites that have tried to upgrade to SHA-2 have seen a backlash due to browser incompatibility. In July, mozilla.org upgraded their site to use a SHA-2 certificate. In doing so they lost around 145,000 Firefox downloads per week due to browser incompatibility. Even google.com (as of November 10, 2014) continues to use SHA-1 for compatibility reasons, despite the company’s push to deprecate SHA-1 in Chrome.
>
> To support both Chrome and Windows XP SP2 it’s necessary to use a SHA-1 certificate that expires before 2016. This is the option we have chosen for CloudFlare-managed certificates.

Comment: I have a feeling SO is actually on a paid plan (possibly under a custom certificate) and that's why they are on an older SHA1 certificate. [This might be a good read](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-and-sha-1-certificates/) about why they are still using SHA1 on paid accounts and using SHA256 on free accounts.

Comment: @KevinBrown Uhm, you linked the same article I have in my answer?

Comment: Just noticed that it was the same link (thought yours was the Universal SSL link). But it does explain why they are still using SHA1, and why you are seeing SHA256 on your own website.

Comment: @KevinBrown Actually it doesn't appear that they're paying for it. If you read the blog, they're using SNI for paid customers so if you support SHA2 you get SHA2. But if you load up the HTTPS SO site you get a SHA1 certificate with an expiration later this year (so Chrome doesn't freak out)

Comment: Pulling specifically from the blog post, "All paid customers now get a CloudFlare-managed SHA-1 certificate that expires in late 2015," seems to line up with what I am seeing from the SSL test as well as local testing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted SHA is not used for encryption, but rather for data integrity/ message authentication (hashing). It is a cryptographic hash function used to make signatures. If it was cracked it might allow or exacerbate complex [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) or perhaps other vulnerabilities, but no one on your network with a sniffer will be able to suddenly read your data in plaintext. See:

- *[SSL encryption, SHA-1 and SHA-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827121)*
- *[Cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)*

Answer (score -2):

SHA-1 is deprecated, because new certificates exists are issued which are [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). However older operating systems (for example, Windows XP and Android before [version 2.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_2.3.E2.80.932.3.2_Gingerbread_.28API_level_9.29) (Gingerbread)) are not capable of validating the SHA-256 certificate.

I guess the lack of support makes the old certificate more useful. An estimated 20 million devices would be broken.

See: [The Register: SHA-1 retirement](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/04/30/sha_2_migration_headaches/)

Comment: are those 20 mln devices the count of old devices that access SO or 20mln devices with internet access, regardless if they access SO or not?

Comment: 20m devices that access the internet

Comment: I'd think there may be very few, if any, that access SO, that 20mln number doesn't sound like relevant user base

Comment: Developers on Windows XP probably have a *lot* of broken tools.

Comment: @Qix To be fair even if a developer is require to develop for and support technology that uses Windows XP they should have newer technology at their disposal that would allow them to make full use of the stack exchange network and general programming resources. While it may be needed to support older technology effort should be made to move off it when it is no longer supported and not getting security updates.